# connecting MATLAB with Weka in web

Tags: matlab, webserver, weka

Is it possible to connect MATLAB with [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/index.html) and upload it to web server? 
I know that I can connect MATLAB with web server, but after connecting Weka with it, is it Ok?

Comment: what is weka? Waikato Environment for Knowledge Analysis? What kind of connection to a web server? ftp?

Comment: I didn't deiced yet to use any specific web server, but yes is it ok with FTP ? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weka is a java application with a java-based [API](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code). Add weka to the java path of matlab and use it. Using java in Matlab is [described in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/using-java-libraries-in-matlab.html).

FTP is supported by [matlab via build in commands](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/ftpclass.html). If you require any other protocol which is not supported by matlab, use a java implementation as described above.